# How do I do the Res glitch and has it been patched?

Tags: borderlands-2

There's an exploit to make it so that whenever a player is downed, they are immediately revived without anyone else's aid. It involves Maya the Siren's Res skill. How do I do it and has it been patched (by patch 1.8.3)?

Comment: One of the skills in her healer tree is being able to use her action power to instantly revive a fallen ally. Is that what you're wondering about? If so this isn't a glitch.

Comment: No. Sorry about the wording. I'll fix it to give a better impression. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Can you share a video or other description of the glitch?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2YYwM1coOU#t=2h7m27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to: (1) Start reviving one player, (2) Res another, (3) finish reviving the former player.
Result: The former player will automatically and immediately get a Second Wind if they enter FFYL mode.

It was patched in [update v1.5.0](https://gearboxsoftware.zendesk.com/entries/22126761--PC-Update-Hot-Fix-Information) (Released April 18, 2013).

> - Fixed an exploit where players could become invincible occasionally through the Siren's Res skill.